# ¿Como hacer girar un objeto 2D girar hacia la posicion de otro objeto?

Tags: unity2d

Presento el siguiente problema, tengo un enemigo que quiero  que gire hacia la posición donde esta el jugador, pero no se que el  hacer el objeto npc sepa hacia que lado tiene que mirar, el juego en cuestion es como si fuera mario bros y no un top down game. mi pregunta es :

¿Que método conocen que para  hacer que el npc sepa hacia que dirección tiene que mirar?.

Answer (score 2):

Una solución típica en 2d:

```
Vector3 direccion = player.position - transform.position;
float angulo = Mathf.Atan2(direccion.y, direccion.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angulo, Vector3.forward);
```

Comment: Presento un problema y es que necesito que otro objeto dentro del objeto padre tome una dirección dada por el npc pero como tengo una rotación diferente en el objeto padre el hijo al inmediatamente activarse la rotación del padre toma un comportamiento diferente. (cabe aclarar que  cuando me refiero  a mi objeto rote lo estoy haciendo es invertir su escala en x.)